# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid. What kind of an error is it?

Tags: vb.net

I Have a Form which takes input of Applied date And changed date.
I'm Sending Changed Date NULL as for now. the code inserts the data properly but shows this error on screen 
"Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid"

I'm using this Function for Date input

```
If ChangedDate <> "" Then
    sSQL = sSQL & ", @ChangedDate= " & gFixQuotes(Format(DateTime.Parse(ChangedDate, InputFormat), SQLLONGDATEFORMAT))
Else
    sSQL = sSQL & ", @ChangedDate=NULL"
End If
```

Comment: Try to use `If Not IsDBNull(ChangeDate) Then .... else ... End If`

Comment: Now Its Not Even inserting 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: That is such a mess.  Is it `ChangedDate` that is `DBNull`?  If so then it is presumably coming from a database.  In that case, why the hell is it text and not an actual `Date` in the first place?

Comment: Its what The standard says in my office.

Comment: @AmneshGoel My Procedure was returning Identity when the table i was inserting into did'nt have a PK .. :p
Stupid mistake I know. But I'm new so :)

Comment: A DBNull value is an unknown value that could be of any data type, by definition.
This is the reason you can't convert it to a string.

Comment: Shafay .. you confused me more now.. Can you explain your problem again..

Comment: I think you're showing us the wrong piece of code. You'll usually get this error when trying to *read* data from the database.

Comment: that is exactly what happened.
look My procedure was returning Identity on insertion
Select @@identity
but My table did'nt had a Primary Key to return.
So thats Why it was showing the error.
It was not about the Changed Date issue.